# what are the hardware requirements to perform an important simulation using OMNT++ & VEINS?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Under ubuntu, what is the hardware(I will buy a Laptop) configuration required to simulate city scenario represented by a 24 hour mobility dataset that covers a 400 km2 (using OMNT++, VEINS and SUMO).

Answer (score 1):

It is a big simulation... But the simulation time will depend on the number of simultaneous vehicles.

**My minimal suggestion:**

RAM: 8GB

Processor: 4 cores

SSD instead of HD (it makes a lot of difference...)